# Microsoft Graph how to request emails for a different user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I understand how this call works (to get my own emails):

```
graphClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().GetAsync();
```

How would I use a similar call do get another user's emails? Would it be something like this?:

```
graphClient.Users["userid"].MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().Top(25).GetAsync();
```

When I execute this, I get this error: "Error in /Home/GetEmails: Caller needs to authenticate."

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this if you request for an App Only Token using App Only permissions for access to the Microsoft Graph.

Read here to learn about the different [Graph Permissions for the Mail Endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#mail-permissions).

I think this only works for AAD accounts, and you must be a Tenant Administrator to consent to these kinds of permissions.

Comment: In addition, this page walks though configuring app only authentication: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service